# Should I use "in" or "at" in the following case?

Tags: prepositions

> We trekked up Jin Mountain **in** New Taipei City.
>
> We trekked up Jin Mountain **at** New Taipei City.

What's the correct choice, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "New Taipei City" sprawls over a large geographical area (2,052.6 square kilometres or 792.5 square miles) including most of the northernmost parts of Taiwan--in fact this "city" is composed of an entire county that was reclassified in 2010 as a "special municipality"--I would use **in** in this case. You can use *at* and not be wrong. But *at* suggests a point, while *in* suggests being *inside* or *contained within* something, in this case this huge sprawling city that used to be a county. A lot of things are **in** New Taipei City, since it covers such a large geographical area.

In most cases it is difficult to think of a mountain being *in* (*inside*) a city, but in the case of this particular city, it is not so difficult.

In sum, *either preposition is fine*. It depends whether you conceive of New Taipei City as a "point" (at) or as a place that encloses things (in). This distinction goes for the use of *in* and *at* as prepositions of place in general. But even if you look at a map of Taiwan, it's difficult to consider New Taipei City as a point on a map, since it spreads over a large area.

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about countries or states, cities, towns, villages, etc. it is always best to use **in**.

The preposition **at** is best used with events, places of business, homes. However there is an exception: when we speak of capitals of countries or states, we can use **in the capital** or **at the capital**, especially when it's viewed as a political/business center.